# Do the functions periodic with period $1$ a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces, contest-math

> Denote by $E$ the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of all mappings from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Rigorously justifying your answer in each case, indicate whether the following subsets of $E$ are vector subspaces of $E$.
>
> $$G=\{f \in E \text{ such that } : f(x) \text{ is periodic with period 1 } \}$$.

G is Vector subspace of E if and only if :

- $G\neq \emptyset$
- if $f,g \in G$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ then $(af+bg )\in G $

Indeed

- Since $f=0$ is always $\in G$ then $G\neq \emptyset$
- let  $f,g \in G$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$

$f$ is periodic with period $1$ ($f(x+1)=f(x)$ for all $x$ )

is $(af+bg)(x+1)=(af+bg)(x) \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ ?

$(af+bg)(x)=af(x)+bg(x)=af(x+1)+bg(x+1)=(af+bg)(x+1)$

Then G is subspace of E

Am i right

Comment: Use $(af+bg)(x)=af(x)+bg(x)$.

Comment: Your definition of a periodic function with period $1$ seems strange to me. Would you say that $f(x) = \sin(4\pi x)$ has period $1$?

Comment: i don't know i need help

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese see please my update to upvote my Question

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese This is an interesting comment. The closedness under addition depends on this. Must $1$ be _the_ (shortest) period, or is it enough that $1$ is _a_ period?

Comment: @Educ: As my initial comment alluded to, and Jeppe Stig Nielsen has accurately articulated, it depends on whether $E$ is the set of functions with $1$ as a period or $1$ as the period. Also, I did not downvote your question.